# How to skip insert to an Oracle table in procedure where specified columns going to insert are null

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I'm inserting lots of rows into a table and some of the columns are blank for some of the rows.

How can I skip insert if some important fields are blank?
for example there is a table 'people' and my important fields are name,cityName and age.

```
   1 INSERT INTO people VALUES('customerid1','name', 'cityName', 50, 'anotherValue')
   2 INSERT INTO people VALUES('customerid2','', '', '' , 'anotherValue')
   3 INSERT INTO people VALUES('customerid3','name', 'cityName', 20, 'anotherValue')
   4 INSERT INTO people VALUES('customerid4','name', 'cityName', 19, 'anotherValue')
```

here 2nd row name,cityName and age are blank.
if those three fields are blank then dont insert that row.this is just an example i have more fields to check so need to avoid 'if condition' to check blank or not.

### another example

```
FUNCTION TEST_FUN (increment_i in VARCHAR2, increment_j IN VARCHAR2,mod_id IN VARCHAR2 ) 
      RETURN numeric IS
          j_val VARCHAR2(100);
          i_val VARCHAR2(100);
      BEGIN
          i_val := increment_i;
          j_val := increment_j;
          IF mod_id != 'loop' THEN
            j_val := i_val;
          END IF;

          INSERT
          INTO TEST.testpartytable
            (
              reffer_id,
              customer_id,
              customer_joint,
              fullname,
              nature,
              counter_bus,
              country,
              status
            )
            VALUES
            (
              REFFER_ID_AR,
              CUSTOMER_ID_ARR(i_val),
              CUSTOMER_JOINT,
              LEGALNAME_KBC_ARR(i_val),
              NATURERE_KBC_ARR(j_val),
              COUNTERBUSACT_KBC_ARR(j_val),
              COUNTRY_KBC_ARR(j_val),
              STATUS
            );
          return i_val;
      END TEST_FUN ;
```

skip insert if 'fullname,nature,counter_bus,country' fields are blank .Datas coming from colletion.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: if you have a plsql procedure simply write an appropriate condition before the insert statement

Comment: use trigger and raise exception

Comment: hi oracle dev thanx for your reply..yes have plsql procedure. you mean to check with if condition for collection is blank for each fields ? .. is there any option without if condition? or u have any example?

Comment: hi gaj u have any example?

Comment: I approach I can suggest is to create a temporary table and store complete data in that table. This table will have no constraint or index. Load this table with loader.Then use insert into <main table> select * from <temp_table> where <column condition>

Comment: can you paste the procedure, I don't know from where you get the values you are inserting

Comment: Trigger is a bad idea. Never use triggers to implement business logic. (Unless you are working on legacy systems)

Comment: dev i updated my question can u check?

Comment: ok ychdziu. i didnt implement i just think thats it. i need new ideas

Comment: @OracleDev i updated question .. Iam using collection and inserting through loop

Comment: just add an IF statement before the insert statement. For example to check if the "name" is not blank use "IF LEGALNAME_KBC_ARR(i_val) is not null THEN" or to add more conditions use "IF LEGALNAME_KBC_ARR(i_val) is not null or NATURERE_KBC_ARR(j_val) is not null THEN"

Comment: The question I also have is where does the "collection" come from, you could limit the calls to the function if you had the collection with the data that you want

Comment: @OracleDev yeah i know this dev. i mentioned in my question that without if condition is there any option or keyword or trigger something.. because i need to apply this to another insert queries

Comment: @OracleDev datas collection through php.appending to collection variables

Comment: I don't see any other solution but removing the empty data from the collection or use IF

Comment: @OracleDev ok dev thanx for your kind replys.. me too didnt get any other solutions :)

Comment: @user3435234 well if you dont want if condition , you can make the column not null and add a raise exception when you get error not null you dont make the insert

Comment: @Moudiz ya moudiz iam luking like this.. what is the real keyword .. column_not_null?

Comment: @user3435234 well you change customer_id to not null, `alter table testpartytable modify customer_id not null` so when you insert youll get an error , you can handle it by raise exception do whatever you want. its not a good approach but maybe it server your needs, beware that in other inserts you have to specify value for this colum

Comment: ya @Moudiz i got your point. now the fields are nullable :yes. but need to think because there are more situation coming in my insert query.

Answer (score 1):

well you can check first if the values are null or not null:

```
declare CHECK_VAL varchar2(100);
BEGIN
select CUSTOMER_ID_ARR(i_val) into CHECK_VAL from dual;
if(i_val is not null) then
insert...
end if;
END;
```

You can alternavely make the column to not null, and raise exeception when you get error for a value not null.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply a NOT NULL constraint to your important columns so that when any of them assigned with a NULL value an error will be raised, specifically ORA -1400 (cannot insert null) exception. You can then catch this exception in your program and just do nothing when this exception is raised.

Sample below,

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_TABLE
(col1 NUMBER NOT NULL, col2 NUMBER NOT NULL);

DECLARE
    CANNOT_INSERT_NULL EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(cannot_insert_null, -1400);
    num NUMBER;
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
        num := 2;
        IF i BETWEEN 3 AND 5 THEN
            num := NULL; //since this is null, insert statement below will error and handled and won't be inserted
        END IF;
        BEGIN
            INSERt INTO test_table
            (col1,col2)
            VALUES
            (i, num);
        EXCEPTION
            WHEN CANNOT_INSERT_NULL THEN
                NULL;
        END;
    END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT *
  FROM test_table;
```